# compile OpenSSL /GmSSL on windows 10 in masm assembly

Tags: c, openssl, masm

I want to compile GmSSL library( a branch of OpenSSL). But I don't know why it failed.

GmSSL on GitHub:https://github.com/guanzhi/GmSSL

I had installed ActivePerl 5.24.3 on my computer. The follow is my compiling parameter:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A-masm
```

But I failed.

```
Configuring GmSSL version 2.5.1 (0x1010004fL)
    no-asan         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_ASAN
    no-crypto-mdebug [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG
    no-crypto-mdebug-backtrace [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_BACKTRACE
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128
    no-egd          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EGD
    no-fuzz-afl     [default]  OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_AFL
    no-fuzz-libfuzzer [default]  OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_LIBFUZZER
    no-gmieng       [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMIENG
    no-heartbeats   [default]  OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-msan         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MSAN
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP
    no-sdfeng       [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SDFENG
    no-skfeng       [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SKFENG
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE
    no-ssl3         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
    no-ssl3-method  [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD
    no-ubsan        [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UBSAN
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
Configuring for VC-WIN64A-masm
NASM not found - please read INSTALL and NOTES.WIN for further details
```

I want to have assembly code about GmSSL's SM3 algorithm on Windows 10.
Who can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears it failed because it couldn't find NASM on the path anywhere. Have you tried installing NASM and install it somewhere on your PATH? https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/snapshots/latest/

Comment: Maybe,you are right. But, I want to conpile it by MASM. I had installed VS2015.

Comment: I hope to get the assembly code of SM3 algorithm.